# Utilizar mais de um h1?

Tags: html5

Se eu já utilizei um **h1** para definir o logo/titulo do meu Header, posso usar mais algum **h1** na página ? ou apenas **h2**.. ?
não lembro onde li, mas posso utilizar h1 em cada article ou section ?

```
<header>
   <h1>logo</h1>
</header>
<section>
   <article>
      <h2>titulo do post</h2>
      <p>descrição</p>
      content..
   </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes usar quantos `h1`, `h2` e outros as vezes que quiseres.

Tem em conta que a função semântica é dar destaque ao conteúdo desse pedaço/tag. Quer em termos visuais quer em termos de SEO (indexação do Google por exemplo). Por isso deves gerir e usar essas tags com cuidado, sentido de organização. Mas podes usar as vezes que quiseres.

Nas [especificações da W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/headings-and-sections.html#headings-and-sections) pode vêr-se este exemplo, com múltiplos `h1`:

```
<body>
    <h1>Apples</h1>
    <p>Apples are fruit.</p>
    <section>
        <h1>Taste</h1>
        <p>They taste lovely.</p>
        <section>
            <h1>Sweet</h1>
            <p>Red apples are sweeter than green ones.</p>
        </section>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1>Color</h1>
        <p>Apples come in various colors.</p>
    </section>
</body>
```

Há tags que só se podem usar uma vêz por página. Entre essas encontram-se `html`, `head`, `base`, `title` e `body`.

Comment: Mt obrigado, acho que eu entendi bem, e tbm eu não conhecia as recomendações do W3C, isso vai ajudar MT ..

Answer (score 3):

De uma forma bem resumida e objetiva, sim, pode usar mais de uma vez.

O H1 apenas define o nível de importância do título.

Se a página contém, por exemplo, uma chamada para 5 artigos, normalmente cada artigo possui um título, então cada chamada terá o título dentro de um H1.

Exemplo:

```
<header>
   <h1>logo</h1>
</header>
<section>
   <article>
      <h1>titulo do post 1</h1>
      <p>descrição</p>
      content..
   </article>
   <article>
      <h1>titulo do post 2</h1>
      <p>descrição</p>
      content..
   </article>
   <article>
      <h1>titulo do post 3</h1>
      <p>descrição</p>
      content..
   </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Para eu colocar meus subtítulos dos artigos em <h2> tenho que criar várias <section> dentro de <article>? Ou posso inserir os <h2> diretamente dentro da <article>?